# Дополнение или определение?

Tags: синтаксис

Волны тумана - слово 'тумана' дополнение или несогласованное определение?

Comment: @школяр-я, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Хотелось бы услышать мнение Людмилы. Учителя ведь не На пустом месте сомневаются.

Answer (score 2):

Это несогласованное определение.

Дополнение

[Определение, способы его выражения](http://www.gramota.ru/book/litnevskaya.php?part5.htm#332)

[Дополнение, способы его выражения](http://www.gramota.ru/book/litnevskaya.php?part5.htm#333)

Comment: А учителя во мнении разошлись. И в цифровых  
к уроку с официального сайта программа выдает ответ дополнение.
Я согласен с вами.Можно ведь заменить на туманные волны.

Comment: Да, конечно! Туманные волны - определение. Волна тумана - н.о. Однако в словосочетании "волны тумана" можно рассмотреть дополнение. Напр.:На берегу можно наблюдать (наблюдать что ?) волны (дополнение) (чего?- тумана -н.о.). Несогласованные определения связаны с определяемым словом управлением или примыканием и выражаются:существительным в косвенном падеже с предлогом или без предлога (в том числе несогласованным приложением). Волны (чего? - тумана - род.пад.). Здесь словосочетание " волны тумана" соединены связью управления.

Comment: Ср.,например: (Я люблю) пьесы Чехова. ( Здесь н.о.). См. ссылку в главном ответе.